# Using Obj-C generated code using WSDLToObj-c Tool

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, wsdl

From my application i need to call a web service to get the list of books in a server. For this purpose the following WSDL link is provided http://demo.kitaboo.com/eBookServices/services/ListOfBooksService?wsdl

Using the WSDL2ObjC Tool available at http://code.google.com/p/wsdl2objc/downloads/list i've generated the equivalent objective-C code for the given WSDL url.

[This is the link](http://code.google.com/p/wsdl2objc/wiki/UsageInstructions) which i referred while implementing to call the web service.

```
#import "MyWebService.h"

MyWebServiceBinding *binding = [MyWebService MyWebServiceBinding];
binding.logXMLInOut = YES;

ns1_MyOperationRequest *request = [[ns1_MyOperationRequest new] autorelease];
request.attribute = @"attributeValue";
request.element = [[ns1_MyElement new] autorelease];
request.element.value = @"elementValue"];

MyWebServiceBindingResponse *response = [binding myOperationUsingParameters:request];

NSArray *responseHeaders = response.headers;
NSArray *responseBodyParts = response.bodyParts;

for(id header in responseHeaders) {
  if([header isKindOfClass:[ns2_MyHeaderResponse class]]) {
    ns2_MyHeaderResponse *headerResponse = (ns2_MyHeaderResponse*)header;

    // ... Handle ns2_MyHeaderResponse ...
  }
}

for(id bodyPart in responseBodyParts) {
  if([bodyPart isKindOfClass:[ns2_MyBodyResponse class]]) {
    ns2_MyBodyResponse *body = (ns2_MyBodyResponse*)bodyPart;

    // ... Handle ns2_MyBodyResponse ...
  }
}
```

I'm unable to interrelate the terms such as (ns1_MyOperationRequest, MyWebServiceBindingResponse, myOperationUsingParameters) that are present in the code.

Any idea on how to go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT for your updated question:

In your header file, add the `ListOfBooksServiceSoapBindingResponseDelegate` and also implement `- (void) operation:(ListOfBooksServiceSoapBindingOperation *)operation completedWithResponse:(ListOfBooksServiceSoapBindingResponse *)response;`

Check the [instructions](http://code.google.com/p/wsdl2objc/wiki/UsageInstructions):

> Once you obtain WSDL2ObjC, code generation is pretty simple.
>
> 1. Launch the app
> 2. Browse to a WSDL file or enter in a URL
> 3. Browse to an output directory
> 4. Click "Parse WSDL"
>
> Source code files will be added to the output directory you've
>   specified. There will be one pair of .h/.m files for each namespace in
>   your WSDL.

In case you didn't notice, you must have downloaded a standalone WSDL2ObjC.app. The window looks like this:

[image]

Comment: @i was editing this ques while you guys answered it, any way thanks

Comment: I edited my answer, but I can't explain much if you don't tell us the exact problem. Be sure to check the sample code that you link to (the one with the FriendsBindingOperation)

Comment: FriendsBinding *bFriends = [[FriendsService FriendsBinding] retain];
        bFriends.logXMLInOut = YES;
      What does Friend service param stand here for?

Comment: @Pranav it should be ListOfBooksServiceSvc in your case. This is the base class that is needed to give you the ListOfBooksServiceSoapBinding which you will need for the rest of your code to make requests.

Comment: Sorry but I can't help you more like that, in the comments. If you study the code in the examples you can easily find the corresponding requests you need to make and if you still have problems, post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Just enter your WSDL link in link and get the code
http://sudzc.com/

Comment: @i was editing this ques while you guys answered it, any way thanks

Comment: its a paid solution, dont we have free or opensource solutions ?